# Is there any API for Facebook to get all the published ads?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I want to get all the `published ads` in the `facebook` searched by `keywords` or `URL's`, I know that you can get your own ads by giving campaign ID but Is there any `API` that will get all the ads not for current user but all user's ads?

Comment: No there is not. What would you do with other companies ads anyway?

Comment: I just want to get how attractive there ads are. how they are using and engaging audience.

Comment: ok, that is not possible

Comment: You can browse active ads here: https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/